# How does Python know there is a local variable before encountering its declaration?

Tags: python, scoping

```
def f(): 
    print("Before", locals())   # line 2
    print(x);                   # line 3
    x = 2                       # line 4
    print("After", locals())    # line 5

x = 1
f()
```

I am aware of the LEGB rule for scoping in Python.

For the above code, when I **comment out line 4**, everything executes normally as expected: for line 3, python does not find variable `x` in the local scope and therefore searches it in the global scope where it finds it and prints 1.

But when I execute the whole code as it is without commenting, it raises `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`.

I do know I can use nonlocal and global, but my question is :

1. How does python know there is a local variable declaration before it has encountered one?
2. Even if it does know there is a variable named x in the local scope (although not yet initialised), why doesn't it shows it in locals()?

I tried finding the answer in similar questions suggestions but failed. Please correct if any of my understanding is wrong.

Comment: The function isn't executed line-by-line. CPython *compiles* the function to byte code, and part of that process is identifying which names are local and which are global using the *entire* definition.

Comment: @chepner That makes sense, but are these _global and local identification_ not exposed to the runtime environment, cause line2 prints empty dictionary?

Comment: Local names are *identified* at compile time, but that doesn't mean the *assignments* happen at compile time.

Comment: To confirm that, you can replace `x=2` with `exec('x=2')`. This way pre-compilation is unable to make `x` local variable, and you see the same outcome as without this line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To some extent, the answer is implementation specific, as Python only specifies the expected behavior, not how to implement it.

That said, let's look at the byte code generated for `f` by the usual implementation, CPython:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Before')
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (locals)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             10 POP_TOP

  3          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 POP_TOP

  4          20 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  5          24 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 ('After')
             28 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (locals)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             34 POP_TOP
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

There are several different `LOAD_*` op codes used to retrieve various values. `LOAD_GLOBAL` is used for names in the global scope; `LOAD_CONST` is used for local values not assigned to any name. `LOAD_FAST` is used for local variables. Local variables don't even exist by name, but by indices in an array. That's why they are "fast"; they are available in an array rather than a hash table. (`LOAD_GLOBAL` also uses integer arguments, but that's just an index into an array of names; the name itself still needs to be looked up in whatever mapping provides the global scope.)

You can even see the constants and local values associated with `f`:

```
>>> f.__code__.co_consts
(None, 'Before', 2, 'After')
>>> f.__code__.co_varnames
('x',)
```

`LOAD_CONST 1` puts `Before` on the stack because `f.__code__.co_consts[1] == 'Before'`, and `LOAD_FAST 0` puts the value of `x` on the stack because `f.__code__.co_varnames[0] == 'x'`.

The key here is that the byte code is generated *before* `f` is ever executed. Python isn't simply executing each line the first time it sees it. Executing the `def` statement involves, among other things:

1. reading the source code
2. parsing into an abstract syntax tree (AST)
3. using the *entire* AST to generate the byte code stored in the `__code__` attribute of the function object.

Part of the code generation is noting that the name `x`, due to the assignment somewhere in the body of the function (even if that function is logically unreachable), is a local name, and therefore must be accessed with `LOAD_FAST`.

At the time `locals` is called (and indeed before `LOAD_FAST 0` is used the first time), no *assignment* to `x` (i.e., `STORE_FAST 0`) has yet been made, so there *is* no local value in slot 0 to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define it before the **f()** function calling,

let's try this one :

```
def f(y):
    print("Before", locals())   # line 2
    print(y);                   # line 3
    y = 2                       # line 4
    print("After", locals())    # line 5

f(x)
x = 1
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's questions.